# Can I inspect a JBoss JMS Queue?

Tags: java, debugging, jboss, jms

I'm debugging an issue I've had with messages posted to a JMS Queue within JBoss 4.2.3. I know I can see the number of messages currently on the queue via the JMX-Console, but want to know if there's a way to get anymore information about the specific messages on the queue currently?

Is any of this available via JMX or can I enable any extra logging?

Or do I have to deploy something using a QueueBrowser?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use hermes jms, which is a JMS management console with a GUI. I haven't tried it with jboss (only with glassfish), but it was working pretty well and I was able to access the individual messages in the queue. Looks like they have a tutorial for jboss here: http://www.hermesjms.com/confluence/display/HJMS/JBoss+Tutorial